# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider WS2003

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Windows Server 2003, IIs 6.0 on deck. .NET 4.0 installed (2.0, 3.5 also installed) SQL 2008 x32

Currently developing ASP.net MVC 4 application.

I got an exception:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

my Connection String is:

```
<add name="DataContextGenerated" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataContext.csdl|res://*/DataContext.ssdl|res://*/DataContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=srv\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Db;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
<add name="MembershipConnection" connectionString="data source=srv\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Db;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"/>
```

And I have a problem with entityconnection, membership works perfectly.

That was "production" same app runned on my dev laptop (W8.1) MSSql2012 works perfectly.

When I'm using my Laptop for Application and production for DB it has same problem - exception

What i can fix to repair that problem?

In c:\windows\assembly there are ...Entity dll

Answer (score 1):

Can you check all the `machine.config` files for your .NET frameworks?

Along with the normal entries for `<DbProviderFactory>` and after them there is a blank entry like this:

```
<DbProviderFactory/>
```

Just remove it from everywhere you find it.

machine.config files can be found in **c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft .NET ...**

Also if the above is not the case and you dont have ANY section for DbProviderFactory, follow this link to insert it properly: [ADD DbProviderFactory entry for SQL Express](http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/11/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact-4_25.html)

Comment: I don't have any DB provider factory entry, i think that can be source of problem, can you supply me with example?

Comment: I tryed to copy this from my local machine, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @user3619176: maybe it is simpler ...do you have sql express installed in your machine? it seems like he cant find it installed.

Comment: Connection strings are ok, i used them for Linq for SQL classes and that works, why entity doesn't work?

Comment: @user3619176 You could follow this to add the dbproviderfactory entry... Link: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/11/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact-4_25.html